# Using HttpContext.Current.Handler in a WebAPI. Migrating from ASP.Net PageMethods to WebAPI

Tags: asp.net-web-api, webforms, asp.net-mvc-routing, httpcontext

I have an ASP.Net WebForms application which is using ASP.Net AJAX PageMethods to render some User Controls. I am trying to get rid of that implementation using WebAPI Controllers and Ajax.

However I am having and issue when trying to access HttpContext.Current.Handler. In the current implementation I use HttpContext.Current.Handler, to set an ID for each TAB as follows (render the UserCrl):

```
        var pageHolder = new AjaxBasePage();
        var viewControl = (UserControl)pageHolder.LoadControl(path);
        if (viewControl is IRenderable<D>)
        {
            if (dataToBind != null)
            {
                ((IRenderable<D>)viewControl).PopulateData(dataToBind, context);
            }
        }
        pageHolder.Controls.Add(viewControl);

        try
        {
            // Get tabID
            var page = (Page)HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler;

            var pageID = page.GetTabID();
            pageHolder.Items.Add("TabID", pageID);

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }
```

In order to set up my WebAPI environment in my current solution I set up the global.asax.cs as follows:

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {         
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(Register);

        var route = RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{tabID}",
        defaults: new { tabID = System.Web.Http.RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
        route.RouteHandler = new MyHttpControllerRouteHandler();
    }
    //To use Attribute Routing
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

    }
```

And to be able to continue using Session:

```
  public class MyHttpControllerHandler : HttpControllerHandler, IRequiresSessionState
    {
        public MyHttpControllerHandler(RouteData routeData) : base(routeData)
        {
        }
    }
    public class MyHttpControllerRouteHandler : HttpControllerRouteHandler
    {
        protected override IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext    requestContext)
        {
            return new MyHttpControllerHandler(requestContext.RouteData);
        }
    }
```

The problem with this approach is that when trying to use HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler it triggers an error saying that "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler' to type 'System.Web.UI.Page'."

I dont know how I can make it works, any ideas what I am doing wrong and How Can I set up the WebAPI to use HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler?